# application can't start if add implementation of AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer in context

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I try to add websocket authorization for my application.

I have following authorization related classes:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String SECURE_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "rockandroll";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/index.html")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/sender.html")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/js/**", "/lib/**", "/images/**", "/css/**", "/index.html", "/","/*.css","/webjars/**", "/*.js").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/websocket").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(new AuthenticationProvider() {

            @Override
            public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
                return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
            }

            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;

                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = SECURE_ADMIN_PASSWORD.equals(token.getCredentials()) ?
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN") : null;

                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token.getName(), token.getCredentials(), authorities);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and web socket security configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketAuthorizationSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(final MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        // You can customize your authorization mapping here.
        messages.anyMessage().authenticated();
    }

    // TODO: For test purpose (and simplicity) i disabled CSRF, but you should re-enable this and provide a CRSF endpoint.
    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I add second class into application - the application can't start and I see following log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'greetingController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'simpMessagingTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerMessagingTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate]: Factory method 'brokerMessagingTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerChannel' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'brokerChannel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannel' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundChannelSecurity' defined in class path resource [hello/WebSocketAuthorizationSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.ChannelSecurityInterceptor]: Factory method 'inboundChannelSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' defined in class path resource [hello/WebSocketAuthorizationSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.MessageSecurityMetadataSource]: Factory method 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.messaging.access.expression.ExpressionBasedMessageSecurityMetadataSourceFactory.createExpressionMessageMetadataSource(Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap;Lorg/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionHandler;)Lorg/springframework/security/messaging/access/intercept/MessageSecurityMetadataSource;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerMessagingTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate]: Factory method 'brokerMessagingTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerChannel' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'brokerChannel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannel' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundChannelSecurity' defined in class path resource [hello/WebSocketAuthorizationSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.ChannelSecurityInterceptor]: Factory method 'inboundChannelSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' defined in class path resource [hello/WebSocketAuthorizationSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.MessageSecurityMetadataSource]: Factory method 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.messaging.access.expression.ExpressionBasedMessageSecurityMetadataSourceFactory.createExpressionMessageMetadataSource(Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap;Lorg/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionHandler;)Lorg/springframework/security/messaging/access/intercept/MessageSecurityMetadataSource;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate]: Factory method 'brokerMessagingTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerChannel' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'brokerChannel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannel' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundChannelSecurity' defined in class path resource [hello/WebSocketAuthorizationSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.ChannelSecurityInterceptor]: Factory method 'inboundChannelSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' defined in class path resource [hello/WebSocketAuthorizationSecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.MessageSecurityMetadataSource]: Factory method 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.messaging.access.expression.ExpressionBasedMessageSecurityMetadataSourceFactory.createExpressionMessageMetadataSource(Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap;Lorg/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionHandler;)Lorg/springframework/security/messaging/access/intercept/MessageSecurityMetadataSource;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
.....
.....
.....
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.messaging.access.expression.ExpressionBasedMessageSecurityMetadataSourceFactory.createExpressionMessageMetadataSource(Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap;Lorg/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionHandler;)Lorg/springframework/security/messaging/access/intercept/MessageSecurityMetadataSource;
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.messaging.MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry.createMetadataSource(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry.java:242) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.socket.AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer$WebSocketMessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry.createMetadataSource(AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.java:193) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.socket.AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource(AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.java:179) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at hello.WebSocketAuthorizationSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$17248f43.CGLIB$inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource$7(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at hello.WebSocketAuthorizationSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$17248f43$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d260b07e.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at hello.WebSocketAuthorizationSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$17248f43.inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 151 common frames omitted
```

you can find full souce code here: https://github.com/gredwhite/demo_ws_app

I put it on github because I am not sure which details important and which - not

Can you please clarify this behavior and explaint how to fix it ?

Comment: Why don't you use the same `5.0.4` version for the `spring-security-messaging`? Why it is `4.0.1.RELEASE`? And why do you need those explicit versions at all since your use Spring Boot plugin?

Comment: @Artem Bilan, thank you - I corrected it but I don't think that it is very importatnt for my hello world example

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` may only mean that you are using incompatible versions. In this case `spring-security-web` and `spring-security-messaging`

Comment: @Artem Bilan I checked it. You are correct. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have this in your dependencies:

```
 compile ('org.springframework.security:spring-security-messaging:4.0.1.RELEASE')
 compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: '5.0.4.RELEASE'
```

That means that you are going to use incompatible versions.

The `spring-security-messaging` depends on the `spring-security-web`.

You should use the same Spring Security version for all its dependencies:

```
 compile ('org.springframework.security:spring-security-messaging:5.0.4.RELEASE')
 compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: '5.0.4.RELEASE'
```

Or let Spring Boot and Dependency Management plugin do the proper version resolution for you.